Is there a better way to put a binary asset to disk so it can be executed using Process.run? Flutter/Dart
I need the help of CLI tools for certain tasks, I added them in the asset of my app
 static Future<String> _assetToDisk(String key) async {
    final byteData = await rootBundle.load(key);
    final bytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    final tempDir = path.join(Directory.systemTemp.path, "AppName");
    await Directory(tempDir).create();
    final executableFile = File(path.join(tempDir, path.basename(key)));
    await executableFile.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    return executableFile.path;
  }

Is there a better way to put a binary asset to disk so it can be executed using Process.run?
